# List web parts with different permissions on same page

Tags: 2010, permissions, view, library

I want to create a page in SP2010 that contains views for lists with different permissions, and a user would see only the lists for which he or she has permissions. When I try adding a restricted list, the user who doesn't have permissions for the list can't see the page at all, but instead gets an Access Denied message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the target audiences feature.

1. While editing the page that is hosting the web parts, select on of them and click on Edit Web Part.
2. On the web part property pane, locate the Advanced section.
3. Locate the Target Audiences property. Inside the input you can search for SharePoint Groups. The SharePoint groups and users that you select here will be the only ones that will see that web part.

In this way you can provide different experiences to different kinds of users.

-Hope this helps